# Recording and visualizing timestamps

Tags: ios, statistics, timer

I'm looking for an iPhone tracking system, which allows me to register periodic timestamps and provide me with various statistics regarding them, e.g. average time between them, perhaps a graph displaying trends in the amount of time between them.

As an example, I would click the "Record time!" button on Monday around lunch, Tuesday in the evening and Thursday in the late afternoon. The app would then be able to show me a graph of a slowly increasing amount of time between each event.

My guess is that I have to look in the "Quantified self" category of apps, but I've been unable to find anything that matches.

The option of exporting data would be nice, but is not required. Anything that can do the recording-part, but lack the data visualization, is also interesting.

If a mobile-friendly website for this exists, it could also very well be relevant.